# What is the origin of the Stack Overflow icon?

Tags: discussion, favicon

I recognize that the icon itself symbolizes a stack that's overflowing and falling over, but is there more to the origin of the icon than that? Who made it? Is there more to it than meets the eye?

I've never really thought about it before until I stumbled upon a video online talking about the history of the 3DS and its hackers, which then showcased [this site](http://www.stargate-3ds.com/) that prominently features an icon very similar to the Stack Overflow icon, if not the exact same. [According to archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170823025407/http://www.stargate-3ds.com/) it's been there since at earliest mid-2017.

I wasn't sure if this would fall into some kind of copyright issue or if the icon is under some kind of common license. Apart from bringing that to light, I thought it'd be interesting to hear the history behind the icon, if there is any.

Comment: This [has been answered on the global Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122636/how-was-the-iconic-stack-overflow-emblem-born) (which actually used to be one-in-the-same as this Stack Overflow Meta, but they were split circa 2014, and some of the Stack Overflow-specific stuff got left behind).

Comment: Ah, I thought it odd it was never asked before. Was searching in the wrong place. Thanks

Comment: No, you were actually searching in the right place. The content was in the wrong place. :-)